# Subscribe to Google Groups without confirmation email

Tags: gmail, google-groups

As a Google Group owner, is it possible to enable those who sign up without needing to click a button in a confirmation email.

Is it just possible to tweak some settings so that when users signs up, they are signed up without having to confirm their subscription?

I know that you can sign up, on Gmail, via `[group-name]+subscribe@googlegroups.com` but this requires a confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

No. Opt-in is legally required.

Anyone could send an email claiming to be From the users address.